# How to Push a message in IBM MQ Through node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jms

I am trying to push a message in IBM MQ for that i am using node js:

I Install `npm install mqlight@1.0`

The code is :

```
var mqlight = require('mqlight');
var recvClient = mqlight.createClient({service: 'amqp://localhost'});
recvClient.on('started', function() {
recvClient.subscribe('NodeQueue');
recvClient.on('message', function(data, delivery) {
          console.log(data);
     });
});


var mqlight = require('mqlight');
var sendClient = mqlight.createClient({service: 'amqp://localhost'});
sendClient.on('started', function() {
    sendClient.send('NodeQueue', 'Hello Node Queue!');
});
```

But I get Following Error:

```
Error: mqlight.js is not currently supported on node-v48-win32-x64
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cdeshma2\node_modules\mqlight\mqlight.js:65:
13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cdeshma2\Desktop\TestWorkSpace\Test\Queue.js
:2:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
```

Which Version of Node js should I use, Any Link for Download??

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution of my problem, 
Simply you need to download the lower release and your code will work: